# How to enter/exit strategy on Fibonacci levels?

Tags: pine-script

I can't make the strategy to enter the trade on the `fibEntry`value. The value is plotted on the chart, right where is supposed to be. It is some problem with exiting the strategy.

I have tried:

`strategy.entry(id="EL", when=fibEntry)`

```
crossEntry = cross(close, fibEntry[1])
crossEntrySince = barssince(crossEntry) < 5

if crossEntry
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true)
```

Here is the code:

````
//@version=4

strategy(title="First baby study / long position / trade set up #2 ", shorttitle="F.B.S.:long #2", overlay=true)


//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 1. Highs and Lows $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


pHigh = pivothigh(1, 1)
pLow = pivotlow(1, 1)


//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2. Fibonacci $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.1 Fibonacci Top $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


float fibTop = na

if pHigh > pHigh[2] or pHigh > pHigh[3] or pHigh > pHigh[4] or pHigh > pHigh[5]

  or pHigh > pHigh[6] or pHigh > pHigh[7] or pHigh > pHigh[8] or pHigh > pHigh[9]
  

   if close[1] > open[1]
   
       fibTop := close[1]
   
   if open[1] > close[1]
   
       fibTop := open[1]


//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.2. Fibonacci Bottom $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


float fibBottom = na

if pLow > pLow[2] or pLow > pLow[3] or pLow > pLow[4] or pLow > pLow[5]

  or pLow > pLow[6] or pLow > pLow[7] or pLow > pLow[8] or pLow > pLow[9]
  
  or pLow > pLow[10] or pLow > pLow[11] or pLow > pLow[12] or pLow > pLow[13] 
   
  or pLow > pLow[14] or pLow > pLow[15]
   
   if close[1] > open[1]
       
       fibBottom := open[1]
       
   if open[1] > close[1]
       
       fibBottom := close[1]


//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.3. Fibonacci 0.272 - Entry Levl $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


var float fibEntry = na

if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[1] 
   fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[1])
else
   if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[2] 
       fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[2])
   else
       if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[3] 
           fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[3])
        
 
//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.4. Fibbonacci -0.272 - Take Profit Level $$$$$$$$$$$$$$


var float fibProfit = na

if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[1]
   fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[1]) * 0.272 + fibTop
else
   if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[2]
       fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[2]) * 0.272 + fibTop    
   else
       if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[3]
           fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[3]) * 0.272 + fibTop
     

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.5. Fibonacci 0.786 - Stop Loss Level $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


var float fibSL = na

if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[1] 
   fibSL := fibTop - 0.786 * (fibTop - fibBottom[1])
else
   if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[2] 
       fibSL := fibTop - 0.786 * (fibTop - fibBottom[2])
   else
       if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[3] 
           fibSL := fibTop - 0.786 * (fibTop - fibBottom[3])
       
//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 3. Enter Trade $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


crossEntry = cross(close, fibEntry)

crossEntrySince = barssince(crossEntry) < 5

if crossEntrySince
   strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true)


//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 4. Take Profit $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

// crossProfit = cross(high, fibProfit)
// if barssince(fibProfit) < 5
//     strategy.exit(id="Long")


//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 5. Stop Loss $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


crossSL = cross(low, fibSL)
if barssince(fibSL) < 7
   strategy.close(id="Long")


//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 6. Plotting $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


plot(fibEntry, transp=50, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, color=#ffe504)
plot(fibProfit, transp=50, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, color=#00ff0a)
plot(fibSL, transp=50, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, color=#00ffe7)
plot(fibTop, color=color.green, offset=-1)
plot(fibBottom, color=color.red, offset=-1)
// plot(pHigh, color=color.green, transp=50,style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, offset=-1)
// plot(pLow, color=color.red, transp=50, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, offset=-1) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you declare your variables `fibTop` and `fibBottom` without the `var` keyword. This causes them to reinitialize to `na` on each bar.
The result was that most of the time, your `fibEntry` was also `na`, causing the `crossEntry` to be `false`.

I've re-written your script (with proper indentation, should be 4 spaces or 1 tab, you had 3 spaces) and put your variables on top of the script.
I've changed the 2 mentiond variables to be declared with `var`.
Does this work for you?

````
//@version=4
strategy(title="First baby study / long position / trade set up #2 ", shorttitle="F.B.S.:long #2", overlay=true)

var float fibEntry = na
var float fibProfit = na
var float fibSL = na

// float fibTop = na
// float fibBottom = na
var float fibTop = na
var float fibBottom = na

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 1. Highs and Lows $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
pHigh = pivothigh(1, 1)
pLow = pivotlow(1, 1)

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2. Fibonacci $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.1 Fibonacci Top $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
if pHigh > pHigh[2] or pHigh > pHigh[3] or pHigh > pHigh[4] or pHigh > pHigh[5] or pHigh > pHigh[6] or pHigh > pHigh[7] or pHigh > pHigh[8] or pHigh > pHigh[9]
    if close[1] > open[1]
        fibTop := close[1]
    if open[1] > close[1]
        fibTop := open[1]

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.2. Fibonacci Bottom $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
if pLow > pLow[2] or pLow > pLow[3] or pLow > pLow[4] or pLow > pLow[5] or pLow > pLow[6] or pLow > pLow[7] or pLow > pLow[8] or pLow > pLow[9] or pLow > pLow[10] or pLow > pLow[11] or pLow > pLow[12] or pLow > pLow[13] or pLow > pLow[14] or pLow > pLow[15]
    if close[1] > open[1]
        fibBottom := open[1]
    if open[1] > close[1]
        fibBottom := close[1]

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.3. Fibonacci 0.272 - Entry Levl $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

//if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[1] 
if fibBottom[1] 
    fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[1])
//else if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[2] 
else if fibBottom[2] 
    fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[2])
//else if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[3] 
else if fibBottom[3] 
    fibEntry := fibTop - 0.272 * (fibTop - fibBottom[3])

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.4. Fibbonacci -0.272 - Take Profit Level $$$$$$$$$$$$$$

// if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[1]
if fibBottom[1]
    fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[1]) * 0.272 + fibTop
// else if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[2]
else if fibBottom[2]
    fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[2]) * 0.272 + fibTop    
// else if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[3]
else if fibBottom[3]
    fibProfit := (fibTop - fibBottom[3]) * 0.272 + fibTop

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 2.5. Fibonacci 0.786 - Stop Loss Level $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

// if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[1] 
if fibBottom[1] 
    fibSL := fibTop - 0.786 * (fibTop - fibBottom[1])
// else if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[2] 
else if fibBottom[2] 
    fibSL := fibTop - 0.786 * (fibTop - fibBottom[2])
// else if barstate.isconfirmed and fibBottom[3] 
else if fibBottom[3] 
    fibSL := fibTop - 0.786 * (fibTop - fibBottom[3])

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 3. Enter Trade $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
crossEntry = cross(close, fibEntry)
crossEntrySince = barssince(crossEntry) < 5

if crossEntrySince
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true)

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 4. Take Profit $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
// crossProfit = cross(high, fibProfit)
// if barssince(fibProfit) < 5
//     strategy.exit(id="Long")

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 5. Stop Loss $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
crossSL = cross(low, fibSL)
if barssince(fibSL) < 7
    strategy.close(id="Long")

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Step 6. Plotting $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
plot(fibEntry, title="fibEntry", transp=50, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, color=#ffe504)
plot(fibProfit, title="fibProfit", transp=50, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, color=#00ff0a)
plot(fibSL, title="fibSL", transp=50, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, color=#00ffe7)
plot(fibTop, title="fibTop", color=color.green, offset=-1)
plot(fibBottom, title="fibBottom", color=color.red, offset=-1)
// plot(pHigh, color=color.green, transp=50,style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, offset=-1)
// plot(pLow, color=color.red, transp=50, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=5, offset=-1) ```
````

I've also changed the code to use the rather new [if-else](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/else-if-statement-18547/) constuct instead of nested if then else.

Also, instead of using

```
if crossEntrySince
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true)
```

You could eliminate the `if` by simply using

```
strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long, when=crossEntrySince)
```

Comment: Thank you, @BjornMistiaen. Unfortunately, it doesn't help. I've even copied and pasted your code to see if there is a difference, but the result is the some. Just this time I get to many false entries. And the script still not using  `fibEntry`, as an entry value.  Thanks for the if-else construct. I didn't' know that.